# Working with /dev/null with cat or cp vs touch

Tags: files, cp, cat, touch, null

In a tutorial about [public key infrastructure](http://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple/) the author sets up a database to work with when setting up a [Root Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority):

```
cp /dev/null ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
cp /dev/null ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db.attr
echo 01 > ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.crt.srl
echo 01 > ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.crl.srl
```

I know `/dev/null` is a special file that has nothing in it and prints no where if you `echo` into it.

It seems like that's what the author is trying to do so I made a small example to test it:

```
$ ls
$ touch foo
$ cp /dev/null bar
$ cat /dev/null > baz
$ ls
bar baz foo
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 mbigras  1264914557  0 Apr 14 14:35 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 mbigras  1264914557  0 Apr 14 14:35 baz
-rw-r--r--  1 mbigras  1264914557  0 Apr 14 14:35 foo
```

- Given we have an empty directory is there any difference between the files `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`?
- Is the point of `cp`ing from `/dev/null` just to set up a file we know is empty?

Answer (score 1):

All result in the same empty file.

Could even just use `>baz2`.  A little more elegant in my opinion, as it isn't reliant on `/dev/null` being present, and doesn't involve invoking additional commands/processes.

Bear in mind that unlike `touch`, the result from `>baz2` will be an empty file even if `baz2` already exists and has some content.

```
$ touch foo
$ cp /dev/null bar
$ cat /dev/null >baz
$ >baz2
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Apr 14 21:40 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Apr 14 21:40 baz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Apr 14 21:40 baz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Apr 14 21:39 foo
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in what happens if the file already exists and has content:

For example, here's a file with content:

```
$ ls -l ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 6 Apr 14 18:06 ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
$ touch ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
$ ls -l ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db       
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 6 Apr 14 18:06 ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
$ cp /dev/null ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
$ ls -l ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db       
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Apr 14 18:06 ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
```

We can see that the `touch` command didn't empty the file, but the `cp` did.

Now, typically, the `:` command can be used instead:

```
: > ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
```

eg

```
$ ls -l ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 6 Apr 14 18:08 ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
$ : > ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db  
$ ls -l ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Apr 14 18:08 ca/root-ca/db/root-ca.db
```

However, in training notes and course work this may be harder to read, thought to be a typo, or similar.  Sometimes using a longer command string is better :-)